# Google Protocol Buffers: JavaScript Example

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

Is it a good choice to use Google Protocol Buffers in JavaScript or is it better to do it with JSON?

Also it'd be great if someone can give me a simple example about Protocol Buffers implementation in JavaScript. The documentation on the Google's site is scarce.

Comment: This SO thread contains more information about the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074147/protocol-buffers-for-javascript

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[edit] Google's open source implementation of protocol buffers is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/main/js)

---

The official protobuf project support only Java, C++, and Python. Not JavaScript.

According to the Wiki of the project, there are three projects porting protocol buffers to JavaScript.

- Protobuf.js: https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js
- protobuf-js: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-js/
- protojs: http://github.com/sirikata/protojs

Protobuf.js is up to date.
protobuf-js has not been updated for two years, so I would favor Protobuf.js.

The question still is "Why?": protobuf may be a bit smaller, especially when a lot of numeric values are transferred, but JSON is simply the more common protocol in the JS space and probably better supported and easier to integrate into other tools.

Comment: Yes, I must agree with you. JSON is the better option in this case. Thanks

Comment: Might come in handy when doing cross domain things, where JSONP is limited to about 2,000 characters due to [IE's limit of the GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url). Have not used it though.

Comment: No doubt about JSON being more fit to most cases. However in my case the message sender is not under my control, and it serializes to protobuf messages, thus we need to parse the messages from javascript.

Comment: @Why: Because you write a message and service methods as proto and you get skeleton of the code for free? Serialization and deserialization on both client/server side.

Comment: Why: the same reason to use protobuf in any other situation. Don't forget that browsers now have WebSocket. Also, desktop applications can be written in JS for Windows 8, and applications, including servers, in Node.

Comment: Code Climate has a great writeup on [the benefits of protobuf over JSON](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/06/05/choose-protocol-buffers/)

Comment: If your system's API already has other binary/protobuf clients, such as Android or iOS devices, then it's more natural to use the existing proto API for a Javascript web client than to build a second copy of the API that offers JSON, just to support a web page.

Comment: The Code Climate article says it's a good idea for services NOT directly consumed by browsers.

Comment: @Why?: Because you are trying to reduce network transfer cost and while JSON is a de-facto standard, if you care about latency or bandwidth costs involved in the communication you can save.

@Why?: Because Google uses it and OBVIOUSLY anything they use MUST be awesome! (Satire anyone?)

Comment: does any of the implementations follow import statements inside .proto files?

Comment: @dmeister I want  `protobuf 2.5.0` to support __Javascript__. Is using __Protobuf.js__ right here ?

Comment: It seems this answer should be updated since (as the answer below says) there is full support for JavaScript now.

Comment: This is outdated answer!

Answer (score 45):

**Update** (28/7/2016):
[Release 3.0.0 was published](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0) - supporting Javascript and other languages as well - in addition to some other features.

Google have recently added alpha support for JS to protobufs: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta-2

Usage:

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --js_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

Screenshots from the release documentation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: While running above command, I am getting "Missing input file" error.

Answer (score 6):

Protobuf 3.0.0 is out:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0

And it support JavaScript natively. The basic information is in the announcement.

We are going to look into it soon.

Answer (score 2):

2023 Update.
The JS implementation had been introduces and branched out of the main protoc app.
Now you can install it using

> npm i grpc-tools

Then use node node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc.js the arguments are the same as for usual protoc. For example:

> node node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc.js --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./dst --proto_path=./proto/ simple.proto

To use it with the usual require also install

> npm i google-protobuf

Then you can simply require the resulting generated file and use it.

Comment: but grpc-tools is for GRPC, i think...

Comment: GRPC is using Protocol Buffers under the hood. Likely there is some overhead but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Protostuff](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/)!

I had a bit of hard time configuring but I'm sure that was more of my issue. You can serialize/deserialize a protobuff/protostuff message to/from JSON. I'm at the early stages of using this but it looks promising so far.

Comment: Curious. Why was this voted down (I have no opinion about Protostuff)?

Comment: @Pimin probably because protostuff is Java and the question is JavaScript?

Comment: @PiminKonstantinKefaloukos person is searching protobuf implementation on *javascript*

Comment: Building Javascript objects for GWT using Protostuff:  http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/wiki/GwtJsonOverlays  .  Totally on topic.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis Fair although I would then call this answer incomplete rather than simply wrong. Since you can't expect every visitor to know how to compile Java to JS or to even know GWT exists, you'd expect at least a pointer to GWT or ideally a working example of getting it working in GWT - since that could be quite the adventure.

Comment: Hey, GWT is google, do THEY even use Protobuf with GWT?  Seems like "they" should be providing this already!