# Binary serialization frameworks or libraries for node.js

Tags: node.js, serialization, frameworks, libraries

I am interested in finding out what binary serialization frameworks/libraries are there for node.js.

I tried to use Apache Thrift, but the documentation is very poor and does not offer any example in this area.

Does anyone know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [ProtoBuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) from Google?

[Here](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) is a JS port that is available on `npm`.

Related:

[Google Protocol Buffers - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912981/google-protocol-buffers-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, that could've been an option - didn't know there was a js library for ProtoBuf, I only looked at the official ones. Anyway, now it's too late.