# Bidirectional Protocol for JSON Payloads in a secure fashion

Tags: json, protocols, network-protocols

I am looking for a secure protocol that supports

- (authentication)
- transsport layer security (TLS)
- bidirectional data streams

to exchange JSON-formatted message payloads.

I've already looked at HTTP-based protocols like BOSH and cometD, but the current problem I see when exchanging data frequently is the HTTPS overhead, since the payload consists of very high frequent measurements and control messages.

Comment: Do you have lots and lots of traffic (say hundreds kBps)? Otherwise I don't think HTTPS overhead is a big concern given the computation power of today's devices.

Comment: yes, we have lots of small payloads (data-measurements)

Comment: Then JSON is inherently unfit for this task, the overhead is pretty high. Can you consider other packetization format at this moment? Try Protobuf/websocket, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912981/google-protocol-buffers-javascript.