# Protocol Buffers byte[] array to node Javascript buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, protocol-buffers, decode

I have a list of ByteStrings generated by java using Google's Protocol Buffers toByteArray() method ([docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#toByteArray())), like below:

```
  ...
  [B@e3bbd6a
  [B@5f9c39ba
  [B@11838ae3
  [B@57dc7b85
  [B@61870e86
  [B@2592cb49
  ...
```

I'm assuming they are UTF-8 byte strings (but I'm not sure) but how would I convert them to JavaScript Buffers? I'm using node's [protocol-buffers](https://github.com/mafintosh/protocol-buffers) package to decode but the format they can decode from is something like below:

```
<Buffer 00 c0 a9 07 12 08 43 61 64 69 6c 6c 61 63>
```

I've tried using node's Buffer api, but haven't had much success.

Any tips on where to start?  I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912981/google-protocol-buffers-javascript) that was asked previously, is that the best way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing byte arrays with their debug string representations. Byte arrays (or Buffers) do *not* necessarily contain UTF-8 text and do not make sense to print as text, and so when you try to print them out in various languages, the runtime will try to create a human-readable text representation of the value as a convenience. Java and Node do this in completely different ways for the same underlying values.

**Java:** The string `[B@e3bbd6a` is not the content of a byte array. When you call `toString()` on a Java `byte[]`, you get some text like this, but all it's telling you is that the object is a byte array located at address `e3bbd6a`. This is not the content of the array, it's just the memory address. (The idea here is that if you printed two different `byte[]` values you would be able to tell if they are the same object based on the addresses matching, but otherwise the text is totally meaningless.)

**Node:** The string `<Buffer 00 c0 a9 ...>` is again just a friendly human-readable string meant for debugging purposes. This isn't the actual low-level representation -- the low-level representation is raw bytes, i.e. the numeric values `00`, `c0`, `a9`, etc.

There is no need to "convert" between the two. If you have a `byte[]` in Java and you write it to a socket or file, and then you read that socket or file in Node into a Buffer object, the Buffer will in fact contain the same data.

Comment: So if I'm writing the list of strings like `[B@e3bbd6a` to a socket, and I use node to read from that socket, how do I get the data so I can decode it?  Am I to understand that my I'm only writing the address of the byte array into the socket and not the actual data?

Comment: Don't write strings to the socket, write the actual byte array. E.g. `OutputStream#write()` takes `byte[]` as the argument, not `String`. If you use that, you are writing the actual bytes, not pointers. On the Node end, reading from a socket normally results in a Buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your advice was just the right push I needed.  Now I got it working and both sides are happily encoding, streaming, and decoding.  Much appreciated :)